# Append Pandas Dataframes in a Loop Function _ Investpy

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am using investpy to get historical stock data for 2 stocks ( TRP_pb ,  TRP_pc )

```
import investpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

TRP_pb = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock='TRP_pb',
country='canada',
from_date='01/01/2022',
to_date='01/04/2022')
print(TRP_pb.head())

TRP_pc = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock='TRP_pc',
country='canada',
from_date='01/01/2022',
to_date='01/04/2022')
print(TRP_pc.head())
```

I can append the two tables by using the append method

`appendedtable = TRP_pb.append(TRP_pc, ignore_index=False)`

---

What I am trying to do is to use a loop function in order to combine these two tables

Here is what I have tried so far

```
preferredlist = ['TRP_pb','TRP_pc']

for i in preferredlist:

    new = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock=i,
                                        country='canada',
                                        from_date='01/01/2022',
                                        to_date='01/04/2022')
    
    new.append(new, ignore_index=True)
```

However this doesnt work.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Since `get_stock_historical_data` returns a `DataFrame`, you can create an empty dataframe before the for loop and `concat` in the loop.

```
preferredlist = ['TRP_pb','TRP_pc']

final_list = pd.DataFrame()
for i in preferredlist:
    new = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock=i,
                                        country='canada',
                                        from_date='01/01/2022',
                                        to_date='01/04/2022')
    
    final_list = pd.concat([final_list, new])
```

Comment: thank you for your help. This is working fine now.

Comment: Glad it works. Can you please accept the answer to close this question?